# ...had been caused by rebels out to discredit - out - meaning?

Tags: grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/ukraine-scrambles-fighter-jets-above-rebel-positions-missile-100357229.html

> Vladyslav Seleznyov, main spokesman for the "anti-terrorist operation", said the violence there had been caused by rebels **out** to discredit the Ukrainian armed forces.

How should one understand that **out**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this usage "out to" means "with the intention of".

So Seleznyov is saying that the rebels were intending to discredit the Ukrainian armed forces.

Comment: This dictionary definition could be useful too: **[be out to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/out#be-out-to-do-something)**: to be aiming to do something or to get something